# List content type permission management

Tags: list, permissions, content-type

I remember being able to manage permissions for list content types in older versions of SP, was this removed for SP2013? If not, how can I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no on SP 2013 and I don't recall this feature existed on SP 2010 or 2007.